# What is this transparent text on my screen

Tags: screen, hardware, oxygenos, android-13, oneplus

I have some strange keyboard silhouettes on my screen which is present all the time. Look at the screenshot closely:
[image]

It's very hard to see on the photo, but if you look beneath the arrow you will see a silhouette. That is a round button of Android keyboard. And there are letters too, they are just too hard to see.

Most of the time it's almost invisible, but on some backgrounds (like on blue in this case) it becomes visible. Also it is not visible on screenshots, that's why I took the photo.

I have no idea what is this. So far I have tried:

- Rebooting
- Switching to NovaLauncher
- Clearing default launcher data

But it didn't help. The fact that it doesn't appear on screenshots makes me think it's something with my display.

Android version: 13

Phone: OnePlus 10 Pro (NE2215)

Comment: Have you considered that it might be [screen burn-in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in)?

Comment: Seems much like it.. It's permanent, right?